# Show div on scrollDown after 800px

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to show a hidden div when scrolling down after 800px from the top of the page. By now I have this example, but I guess it needs modification in order to achive what I am looking for.

EDIT:

[And when scrollUp and the height is less the 800px, this div should hide]

HTML:

```
<div class="bottomMenu">
  <!-- content -->
</div>
```

css:

```
.bottomMenu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll( function(){
        $('.bottomMenu').each( function(i){
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyKar/) of my current code.

Comment: Have you tried doing it? All you need to do is determine if you are more then 800 pixels down and then show a div.

Comment: Yes I tried! But how to determine?

Answer (score 245, accepted):

**If you want to show a div after scrolling a number of pixels:**

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/ZyKar/3/)**

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 800) {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 800) {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1600px;
}
.bottomMenu {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Scroll down... </p>
<div class="bottomMenu"></div>
```

Its simple, but effective.

[Documentation for .scroll()](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)
[Documentation for .scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

---

**If you want to show a div after scrolling a number of pixels,**

### without jQuery:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/smc8ofgg/)**

```
myID = document.getElementById("myID");

var myScrollFunc = function() {
  var y = window.scrollY;
  if (y >= 800) {
    myID.className = "bottomMenu show"
  } else {
    myID.className = "bottomMenu hide"
  }
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", myScrollFunc);
```

```js
myID = document.getElementById("myID");

var myScrollFunc = function() {
  var y = window.scrollY;
  if (y >= 800) {
    myID.className = "bottomMenu show"
  } else {
    myID.className = "bottomMenu hide"
  }
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", myScrollFunc);
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}
.bottomMenu {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  left: -100%;
}
.show {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="myID" class="bottomMenu hide"></div>
```

[Documentation for .scrollY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY)
[Documentation for .className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className)
[Documentation for .addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

---

**If you want to show an element after scrolling to it:**

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/ZyKar/1067/)**

```
$('h1').each(function () {
    var y = $(document).scrollTop();
    var t = $(this).parent().offset().top;
    if (y > t) {
        $(this).fadeIn();
    } else {
        $(this).fadeOut();
    }
});
```

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  //Show element after user scrolls 800px
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 800) {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();
  }

  // Show element after user scrolls past 
  // the top edge of its parent 
  $('h1').each(function() {
    var t = $(this).parent().offset().top;
    if (y > t) {
      $(this).fadeIn();
    } else {
      $(this).fadeOut();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1600px;
}
.bottomMenu {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
}
.scrollPast {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
h1 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Scroll Down...</p>
<div class="scrollPast">
  <h1>I fade in when you scroll to my parent</h1>

</div>
<div class="scrollPast">
  <h1>I fade in when you scroll to my parent</h1>

</div>
<div class="scrollPast">
  <h1>I fade in when you scroll to my parent</h1>

</div>
<div class="bottomMenu">I fade in when you scroll past 800px</div>
```

Note that you can't get the offset of elements set to `display: none;`, grab the offset of the element's parent instead.

[Documentation for .each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)
[Documentation for .parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)
[Documentation for .offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

---

**If you want to have a nav or div stick or dock to the top of the page once you scroll to it and unstick/undock when you scroll back up:**

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyKar/1697/)**

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    //stick nav to top of page
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    var navWrap = $('#navWrap').offset().top;
    if (y > navWrap) {
        $('nav').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
        $('nav').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});

#navWrap {
    height:70px
}
nav {
    height: 70px;
    background:gray;
}
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
}
```

```js
$(document).scroll(function () {
    //stick nav to top of page
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    var navWrap = $('#navWrap').offset().top;
    if (y > navWrap) {
        $('nav').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
        $('nav').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    height:1600px;
    margin:0;
}
#navWrap {
    height:70px
}
nav {
    height: 70px;
    background:gray;
}
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
}
h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Zombie ipsum reversus ab viral inferno, nam rick grimes malum cerebro. De carne lumbering animata corpora quaeritis. Summus brains sit, morbo vel maleficia? De apocalypsi gorger omero undead survivor dictum mauris. Hi mindless mortuis soulless creaturas,
  imo evil stalking monstra adventus resi dentevil vultus comedat cerebella viventium. Qui animated corpse, cricket bat max brucks terribilem incessu zomby. The voodoo sacerdos flesh eater, suscitat mortuos comedere carnem virus. Zonbi tattered for solum
  oculi eorum defunctis go lum cerebro. Nescio brains an Undead zombies. Sicut malus putrid voodoo horror. Nigh tofth eliv ingdead.</p>
<div id="navWrap">
  <nav>
    <h1>I stick to the top when you scroll down and unstick when you scroll up to my original position</h1>

  </nav>
</div>
<p>Zombie ipsum reversus ab viral inferno, nam rick grimes malum cerebro. De carne lumbering animata corpora quaeritis. Summus brains sit, morbo vel maleficia? De apocalypsi gorger omero undead survivor dictum mauris. Hi mindless mortuis soulless creaturas,
  imo evil stalking monstra adventus resi dentevil vultus comedat cerebella viventium. Qui animated corpse, cricket bat max brucks terribilem incessu zomby. The voodoo sacerdos flesh eater, suscitat mortuos comedere carnem virus. Zonbi tattered for solum
  oculi eorum defunctis go lum cerebro. Nescio brains an Undead zombies. Sicut malus putrid voodoo horror. Nigh tofth eliv ingdead.</p>
```

Comment: is there any way to specify y in percentage ?

Comment: This is great, thanks, very useful. My only comments are that it doesn't cover the case where a user goes back to a page, or indeed refreshes the page, and is already at a particular point in the page. It only acts on scroll. There needs to be something on page load to check the position in order to make this complete. Also that scrolling back up and down repeatedly around the break point will fire off numerous fades that will all stack up. Any existing fade should be cancelled by a new one.

Comment: Sorry just one more comment, why put the scrollTop value in a variable to only access it once? It could just be checked directly. That line could be replaced with a call to stop() to fix the second issue raised above, and keep the number of lines of code down, for the jQuery version at least.

Comment: Is it possible to show element onscroll a single time and never hide again on scroll ?

Answer (score 9):

You've got a few things going on there. One, why a class? Do you actually have multiple of these on the page? The CSS suggests you can't. If not you should use an ID - it's faster to select both in CSS and jQuery:

```
<div id=bottomMenu>You read it all.</div>
```

Second you've got a few crazy things going on in that CSS - in particular the z-index is supposed to just be a number, not measured in pixels. It specifies what layer this tag is on, where each higher number is closer to the user (or put another way, on top of/occluding tags with lower z-indexes).

The animation you're trying to do is basically .fadeIn(), so just set the div to display: none; initially and use .fadeIn() to animate it:

```
$('#bottomMenu').fadeIn(2000);
```

.fadeIn() works by first doing display: (whatever the proper display property is for the tag), opacity: 0, then gradually ratcheting up the opacity.

Full working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/sMyfT/

CSS:

```
#bottomMenu {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0; bottom: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 60px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

JS:

```
var $win = $(window);

function checkScroll() {
    if ($win.scrollTop() > 100) {
        $win.off('scroll', checkScroll);
        $('#bottomMenu').fadeIn(2000);
    }
}

$win.scroll(checkScroll);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also, do this.

```
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 800) {
      #code here
   } else {
      #code here
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**SCROLLBARS & `$(window).scrollTop()`**

What I have discovered is that calling such functionality as in the solution thankfully provided above, (there are many more examples of this throughout this forum - which all work well) is only successful when scrollbars are actually visible and operating.

If (as I have maybe foolishly tried), you wish to implement such functionality, and you also wish to, shall we say, implement a minimalist "clean screen" free of scrollbars, such as at **[this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll)**, then `$(window).scrollTop()` will not work.

It may be a programming fundamental, but thought I'd offer the heads up to any fellow newbies, as I spent a long time figuring this out.

If anyone could offer some advice as to how to overcome this or a little more insight, feel free to reply, as I had to resort to show/hide onmouseover/mouseleave instead **[here](http://www.collyg.com/architecture)**

Live long and program, CollyG.