# jQuery window scroll stop firing as user scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

When the user scrolls down a certain number of pixels, I fix the header. However, is there a way to stop calling the window scroll function after the user satisfies the logic in place? I assume that this is not good for performance. See screenshot of my console (http://d.pr/i/OHDX)

```
$window.scroll(function() {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.header').addClass('fixed');
        console.log('fix header'); 
    }
    else {
        $('.header').removeClass('fixed');
        console.log('unfix header'); 
    }

}
```

Comment: you could use a boolean to cheapen the cost of the operation, like "if (!alreadFixed && $window.scrollTop() > 100)"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show div on scrollDown after 800px](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798360/show-div-on-scrolldown-after-800px)

Comment: @cernunnos That would break the function after fixing so that it couldn't be unfixed later (after scrolling back up to the top), because JS would stop calculating the scrollTop.

Answer (score 3):

You have to keep checking the scroll position. I assume you'll want to unfix it when the user scrolls back up to 100?

Your current implementation is fine, performance-wise. One thing you could add is a check to see if the class isn't already added, or keep a toggle so you *know* if the class is there (instead of checking).

```
$window.scroll((function() {
    var fixed = false, elem;
    return function () {
        var should_fix = $window.scrollTop() > 100;
        elem = elem || $('.header');
        if (should_fix !== fixed) {
            if (should_fix) {
                elem.addClass('fixed');
                console.log('fix header'); 
            } else {
                elem.removeClass('fixed');
                console.log('unfix header'); 
            }
            fixed = should_fix;
        }
    };
}()) // immediate invocation, because it's awesome
```

Comment: Technically, the `$('.header')` could be cached outside of the handler as well to improve performance and use less DOM interaction. But that's only if it's a static element and isn't added/removed dynamically.