# Affect element when scrolled down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I have a `<div>` on my website, whose CSS attributes I want to change whenever I have scrolled down 10px of the website. How can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15800696/1947286 this should steer you in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var elementTop = $('.someDiv').offset().top; 
    var position = elementTop- $(window).scrollTop();
    if(position == 10){
      //do something

   }
  });   
});
```

I think this may work, i havent tested it yet but give it try..

Also this jquery function should be really helpful, you also check it out:
http://api.jquery.com/position/