# Floating social media reveal/appear past certain point scrolling fixed position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Had some trouble wording my question above *blush*. Anywho...

Tried searching for this, nothing seems to address my issue. So...

I've seen this new "thing" lately (couple websites) where they have a fixed position div (social media) that gets revealed (appears...as if by magic only I know it's just javascript or jquery or whathaveyou!) when you scroll past a certain point on the page.

Here's an example of what I want >>>
http://digital-photography-school.com/how-to-photograph-strangers-the-100-strangers-project

When you scroll down the page, the social media bar to the left of the page gets revealed, or appears.

I'm self-taught, so I do know HTML and CSS (enough). However, when it comes to javascript / jquery, I can get lost FAST!

So, please, I beg you, when (and if) answering ... if you're going to give me javascript / jquery besides HTML and CSS, please please please tell me exactly where to put the java / jquery in relation to the HTML.

My platform: blogspot (and yes, I know how to host javascript directly on blogger, so I don't need external files / links). Just tell me where to add it, ex: in the head section or right below/above the HTML itself... you know what I mean *hopeful*!

I've got the social media div fixed on my page now -- I just need to be able to make it appear past a certain point when scrolling.

If it helps you, use the same positions, sizes, etc. as in the website example above. I'll do whatever I have to to apply the styling to my own site.

I cannot post link to my actual site because it's not ready to go live yet.

Many thanks in advance. :-)

!!!!!!!!!!UPDATE!!!!!!!!!!

OK, it took some doing, but I managed to find what I was looking for right here on this site! I had to adapt it to my situation, but it worked like a charm and only took a few mins to implement.

This is the javascript I used just below the div within the HTML:

```
$(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 500) {

        $('#social-media').slideDown(0);

    }else if($(document).scrollTop() < 500){

        $('#social-media').fadeOut(0);
    }
});
})
```

And this is the CSS:

```
#social-media {
background: white;
width: 150px;
height: auto;
position: fixed;
z-index:1000;
top: 20px;
display: none;
}
```

Did the trick! And I answered my own q, too! In case anyone was having the same problem.

Thanks for everything -- I come here again and again -- really helped me a lot over the years!

Comment: Do you know `blogger` API? like the current post title and its permalink? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15800696/2151050

Comment: Basically, if it's not HTML or CSS (and if I can't simply copy and paste it when it comes to java, etc.) then ... no. :-( But, if it's something I must do in order to achieve this effect, then by all means... I'm ready to learn! Thanks!

Comment: Found the answer on this site! Adapted to my needs. Thanks for listening! ;-)