# Make <div> appear upon scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I am new to Javascript, so I apologize if this is a mess.  After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798360/show-div-on-scrolldown-after-800px), I implemented the code necessary to make a div appear after the user starts to scroll.  When I put the code into JSFiddle (**http://jsfiddle.net/EnzoMac/ZyKar/1212/**) it works perfectly.  However, it does not work at all on my website.  It is in the JSFiddle, but here is my code:

HTML/ JavaScript:

```
<div class="backtotop"> <a href="#">Back to Top</a></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 1) {
        $('.backtotop').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.backtotop').fadeOut();
    }

});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.backtotop
    {
        display: none;
        width:200px;
        height:inherit;
        position:fixed;
        bottom:0;
        right:0;
        border:thin solid black;
        background:lightgray;
        color:black;
        z-index:1;
        text-align:center;
    }

.backtotop a {
    color:black;
    font-family:calibri;
}
```

Basically, my question is this:  Why doesn't my code work?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Probably there are many reasons. Can you provide a link to your website?

Comment: Your CSS is incomplete and can you show us how you imported jQuery?

Comment: **Alek--** http://alphaoneent.com/new%20%201.php.  It is a work in progress, so it is still a bit of a mess.  My problem is solved, however.

Comment: **Shahar--** I didn't import jQuery, which I found was my problem.  Also, what is wrong with my CSS?  If you referring to the declaration, I just didn't put that in the sample above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using jQuery install link anywhere before this code? And if yes, then check your javascript console and see what errors are there.
jQuery Install Link:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry.  I forgot. Will do.