# How to make a div appear and disappear on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm currently trying to get a div container to slide in from one side once the user has scrolled down a certain amount of px and disappear after the user has scrolled down another set amount of px.

This page has what I want to do - http://2014.igem.org/Team:CU-Boulder

If anyone can help me, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show div on scrollDown after 800px](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798360/show-div-on-scrolldown-after-800px)

Comment: can I have several of those appear if I use that code? Also, I don't think it helps me with the slide in aspect. I don't want it to fade in :)

Comment: okay, that's not what I want. If you check the link provided it illustrates what I am trying to do.

Comment: ok @Aoife, I answered to show how you can get scroll data and use it to build your logic. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To get user's scroll data you can use `scrollTop()` jQuery method.

> **Description:** Get the current vertical position of the scroll bar for
>   the first element in the set of matched elements or set the vertical
>   position of the scroll bar for every matched element.

For example:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentHeight = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (currentHeight > 200) {
        // some action
    }
    if (currentHeight > 300) {
        // another action
    }
});
```

You might be interested looking at [this WOW plugin](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/), or at [this scrollrevealjs](http://scrollrevealjs.org/).