# making div full height of screen with other divs after

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a homepage with multiple sections.

```
<div id="section1">
    <!-- This needs to be the full height of the screen -->
</div>
<div id="section2">

</div>
<div id="section3">

</div>
```

I would like `section1` to be the full height of the screen and then the user can scroll down to see `section2` and `section3` - can this be done with CSS alone or will I need JS to set this dynamically?

Comment: Fair point - didn't see that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for JavaScript here. With with simple css you can do it easily:

```
#section1{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block; // or inline-block - Optional
}
```

You may have to set the `body` & `html` tags `height:100%` too, but not always.

Comment: When using percentage values for height the parent element has to have a height set

Answer (score 2):

You can use [viewport](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/) units

**CSS**

```
#section1{
    display: block;
    background: #000;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/13/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this-

```css
    html, body{height: 100%;}
    #section1{background: red;min-height:100%;}
```

```html
<div id="section1">
   s <!-- This needs to be the full height of the screen -->
</div>
<div id="section2">

</div>
<div id="section3">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 800) {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798360/show-div-on-scrolldown-after-800px)