# how to make the content appear on scrolling down the webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have seen website where content appear as I scroll down the webpage. I have this code but its not working. Can you guide and give proper explanation.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Take your div into one js variable
  var div = $("#divToShowHide");
  //Take the current position (vertical position from top) of your div in the variable
  var pos = div.position();
  //Now when scroll event trigger do following
  $(window).scroll(function () {
   var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
   //Now if you scroll more than 100 pixels vertically change the class to AfterScroll
   // I am taking 100px scroll, you can take whatever you need
   if (windowpos >= (pos.top-100)) {
     div.addClass("AfterScroll");
   }
   //If scroll is less than 100px, remove the class AfterScroll so that your content will be hidden again 
   else {
     div.removeClass("AfterScroll");
   }
   //Note: If you want the content should be shown always once you scroll and do not want to hide it again when go to top agian, no need to write the else part
 });
});
```

```css
.BeforeScroll
{
  height: 100px; /*Whatever you want*/
  width: 100%; /*Whatever you want*/
  display: none;
}


/*Use this class when you want your content to be shown after some scroll*/
.AfterScroll
{
  height: 100px; /*Whatever you want*/
  width: 100%; /*Whatever you want*/
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "divToShowHide" class = "BeforeScroll">Content you want to show hide on scroll
 </div>
```

Comment: refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798360/show-div-on-scrolldown-after-800px

Comment: your link is enlightening... thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you would like to make some animation also, I'll suggest you [AOS](http://michalsnik.github.io/aos/)

It's an Animate On Scroll Library and you can make the content appear on scrolling down

---

How to use:

adding "data-aos="animation name"" to HTML tags would do the trick:

```
<div class="topBar" data-aos="fade-in">
```

after you add in :

```
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.1.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

in head section and add:

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.1.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
```

before the end of body tag.

a quick example:
https://codepen.io/karenmio/pen/KxGewG

there are variations that you can learn from this but the related site does try to sell you courses, let me know if this link is not proper/or take it out:
https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/MmxQMG

Comment: How to use a library. I mean to put it to work...I have never used a library before

Comment: There is a documentation for it here on github https://github.com/michalsnik/aos
and to install it  just add 
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.0.4/dist/aos.css">
in the head tag  if you want to add a cdn link
and before body close tag add this
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.0.4/dist/aos.js">

it's very easy to user just open the documentation on Github

Comment: Okay great. Ill check. Btw please vote my question so that i dont get blocked

Comment: I wish i can :) , but I'm less than 15 reputation now :'D.

Comment: How to add this in wordpress site?

Comment: can we have a chat in private. I tried AOS but I think im not getting it properly

Comment: sure we can have a private chat if you wish, and if you  wants my  contacts they are in my portfolio in my stackoverflow profile

Comment: Whatever happened to pure JS solutions without third party libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I will give a an a example with scrollrevealjs

include the library like that:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/scrollreveal.js/3.3.1/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
```

then in your js file just init the library

```
window.sr = ScrollReveal();
```

and then just add the class of the component you like to animate

```
sr.reveal('.YourClass1');
sr.reveal('.YourClass2');
```

here you will find how to work with this library :)

https://github.com/jlmakes/scrollreveal.js

Comment: Okay thanks ill try. Btw please vote my question up so that i dont get blocked, its a genuine querrry

Comment: Whatever happened to pure JS solutions without third party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var div = $("#divToShowHide");

  var pos = div.position();

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(pos.top)
    if (windowpos > pos.top && pos.top+500 > windowpos) {
      div.addClass("AfterScroll");
       div.removeClass("BeforeScroll");
     
    } else {
       div.addClass("BeforeScroll");
      div.removeClass("AfterScroll");
     
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1200px;
}
#divToShowHide{
  top:100px;
position:fixed;
}
.BeforeScroll {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
.AfterScroll {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divToShowHide" class="BeforeScroll">Content you want to show hide on scroll
</div>
```

Comment: Whatever happened to pure JS solutions without third party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some of the popular JS libraries such as:

http://scrollmagic.io/

https://scrollrevealjs.org/

Good luck :)))

Comment: how to use js libraries...I have no idea

Comment: Sure give example. A link or something