# how to show a div after 500px using pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web

i have a `<button>` calls a `function` that scroll to the top of the page,
how to appear this button automatically after 800px. using pure JavaScript Only?

```html
<button class="button">
  GO To UP
</button>
```

```js
var button = document.querySelector(".button");

button.onclick = function () {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
};
```

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798360/show-div-on-scrolldown-after-800px/15800696

Comment: This question answers your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798360/show-div-on-scrolldown-after-800px

Comment: i need pure JS not Query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be having a hidden class on the button, and in css we can give the visibility of this class to be hidden.

```css
.hidden {
  visibilty: hidden;
}
```

For handling the scroll functionality we can use this function

```js
var button = document.querySelector(".button");

button.onclick = function(){
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    var y = window.scrollY;
    if (y >= 500) {
        button.classList.remove("hidden");
    } else {
        button.classList.add("hidden");
    }
});
```