# I need a sticky div at the bottom after scrolling for a bit

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I need a sticky div that only shows after a certain amount of scrolling is done.

**I AM USING REACTJS. JQUERY WON'T HELP**

I am able to get the sticky div from the **starting** but I want the **yellow sticky div** to show once the whole **Paragraph 1** is scrolled.

This is what I am getting

[image]

This is something I want.. 
**when paragraph 1 is showing**
[image]

and once the **paragraph 1** is scrolled
then i want the sticky div to appear on bottom like this

[image]

P.S : I was not allowed to show the text so  I used lorem ipsum instead. Sorry for heavy text inconvience.
And Yes I am using React.js in the project.
Experts Please Help

```css
div.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p><strong>Paragraph1 <br><br></strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.</p>

<p><strong>Paragraph 2 <br><br></strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.</p>
<p><strong>Paragraph 3 <br><br></strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.</p>

<div class="sticky">I will stick to the screen when you reach my scroll position</div>

<p><strong>Paragraph 4 <br><br></strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.</p>
```

Comment: You want once that paragraph is complete show sticky at top?

Comment: at the bottom. I want the sticky div to to START showing and of course stick at the bottom once the **paragraph 1 is completed scrolled**

Comment: I think this should help you with the first part of your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798360/show-div-on-scrolldown-after-800px

Comment: Its already sticky to bottom by default. You want it should sticky again one *once paragraph 1 is completely scrolled*?

Comment: Its sticking from the very beginning. I don't want it to even **show** until **paragraph 1**  is scrolled up. See the picture 2 & 3. When the paragraph 1 is visible - the sticky div doesn't show and once the paragraph 1 is scrolled and paragraph 2 is at top after then the sticky div starts showing

Comment: Look at my link!

Comment: Yes. that could grab me some help. Can it be anyway done without using javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery.fn.isInViewport = function () {
    //Calc Y-Coordinate of Element
    var elementTop = jQuery(this).offset().top;
    //Adds Y-Coord + Height of Element
    var elementBottom = elementTop + jQuery(this).outerHeight();

    //Calculates current scroll position
    var viewportTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(this).outerHeight();
    
    //Calculates current scroll position plus height of viewport
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + jQuery(window).height() - (jQuery(this).outerHeight() * 2);

    //Checks if Element is in Viewport
    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
      //Is Element in Viewport?
      if (jQuery('.sticky').isInViewport()) {
          jQuery('.sticky').addClass('fixed');
      }
  });
})
```

```css
.sticky {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.sticky.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><strong>Paragraph1 <br><br></strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.</p>

<p><strong>Paragraph 2 <br><br></strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.</p>
<p><strong>Paragraph 3 <br><br></strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.</p>

<div class="sticky">I will stick to the screen when you reach my scroll position</div>

<p><strong>Paragraph 4 <br><br></strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.</p>
```

This should be what you want (using JS and jQuery) Sorry if that's a bit much to use but that's the way I have for you now.

Comment: this did not solve my problem when I scrolled back to the top the div is still stick and not disappeared.

Comment: Ah ok sorry then. I thought you just wanted it to appear and stick, not that it disappears again. That makes my function quite useless then. You should add that in the question

Comment: a Few Modifications in your answer would work but another big problem is that I am using Reactjs which I mentioned and It's preferred not use Jquery in React

Answer (score 0):

This is Vanilla JS solution. I hope it solves your problem.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', isScrolledIntoView);

function isScrolledIntoView() {
    const el = document.querySelector(".sticky");
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    var elemTop = rect.top;
    var elemBottom = rect.bottom;

    // Only completely visible elements return true:
    var isVisible = (elemTop >= 0) && (elemBottom <= window.innerHeight);
    
    if(isVisible) {
      el.style.opacity = 1;
    } else {
      el.style.opacity = 0;
    }

}
```

```css
 div.sticky {
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      position: sticky;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: yellow;
      padding: 25px;
      font-size: 20px;
      opacity: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <p><strong>Paragraph1 <br><br></strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.</p>

    <p><strong>Paragraph 2 <br><br></strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.</p>
    <p><strong>Paragraph 3 <br><br></strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.</p>

    <div class="sticky">I will stick to the screen when you reach my scroll position</div>

    <p class="test1"><strong>Paragraph 4 <br><br></strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus a a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.</p>
```