# How to show an element on scroll down with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, scroll

I want to show a button on my website when a user scrolls down on their mobile by 200px. But, I don't want the button to disappear when they scroll back to the top...it stays there until they refresh or navigate another webpage.

I have the following at the moment which makes the button disappear when the user scrolls back up. How do I amend the code so the button does not disappear on scrolling up?

Note - I am using WordPress. The below Javascript is in an HTML block and the CSS is within the Custom CSS for the button.

```js
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var offset = 200
    $(window).on('load scroll', function(){
        
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > offset ){
            $('body').addClass('show')
        }else{
            $('body').removeClass('show')
        }
    })
    </script>
```

```css
selector{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
body.show selector{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: https://devforhelp.com/code4.html can you check this? and I have modified some code

Comment: Can't you just remove the else block, so the class is never removed again?

Comment: This question might also be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798360/show-div-on-scrolldown-after-800px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the .show class whenever the scroll is past the offset and then you are removing it when it isn't. It should be enough just to remove the else clause.

```
var offset = 200;
$(window).on("load scroll", function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset) {
    $("body").addClass("show");
  }
});
```

Comment: You can add `.off('scroll')` if you don't need it anymore